# How can I override magic methods?

Tags: python, magic-methods, python-3.x

Today, I was reading a book about python and I got to know that there are some magic methods such as `__add__` and `__mul__`.

But, in the book, there is no explanation on how to use them.

So, I tried to figure it out by myself. But, I couldn't figure out how to override magic methods.
Here is the code I tried.

```
>>> class Num(int):
...     def __init__(self, number):
...             self.number = number
...     def __add__(self, other):
...             self.number += other*100
...             return self.number
... 
>>> num = Num(10)
>>> num.number + 10
20
```

Could anyone please help me understand how these magic methods work?

Comment: If you want your `__add__` to take effect, you need to add to `num`, not `num.number`.  Try `num + 10`.

Comment: oh, thank you!! It works! Now, I need to think of how I can take advantage of these magic methods.

Comment: Please be aware of the fact that `__add__` is not supposed to modify the object it operates on, but return a new one. What you do is essentially `__iadd__`. Normally, one would do `def __add__(self, other): return Num(self.number + other * 100)` and `def __iadd__(self, other): self.number += other * 100; return self`

Comment: @glglgl Thank you for giving me the information! it is very helpful!!

Comment: Why store a `number` attribute to a subclass of `int`? The object itself is the number. Generally one overrides `__new__` when subclassing an immutable type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Num:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def __add__(self, other):
        self.number += other*100

>> num = Num(10)
>> num.number
10
>> num + 10  # note that you are adding to num, not to num.number
>> num.number
1010
```

That's how overriding `__add__` works. Version with `return`:

```
class Num:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.number + other*100

>> num = Num(10)
>> num.number
10
>> num + 10  # again adding to num
1010
>> num.number
10
```

So basically when Python sees

```
x + y
x += y
x * y
x *= y
etc
```

it translates it to

```
x.__add__(y)
x.__iadd__(y)
x.__mul__(y)
x.__imul__(y)
etc
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [12]: class Num(int):
    ...:      def __init__(self, number):
    ...:              self.number = number
    ...:      def __add__(self, other):
    ...:              #self.number += other*100 #why do you want to do other*100?
    ...:              return Num(self.number+
    ...:                         Num(other).number) #wrap "other" with "Num"
                                                    #in case "other" is an "int"

In [13]: num = Num(10)
    ...: print num+10
20
```

Actually, you don't need to override `__add__` if your `Num` is a subclass of `int`. Simply call `super` in `__init__` would suffice:

```
In [19]: class Num(int):
    ...:     def __init__(self, *args):
    ...:          super(Num, self).__init__(args)

In [20]: Num(10)
Out[20]: 10

In [21]: Num(10)+10
Out[21]: 20
```

and this way no other attribute like `self.number` is needed.

Comment: @eryksun may I ask what's the disadvantages calling super in this case?

Comment: @eryksun well it's true if there is no other instance attribute ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to override the method of your *class* and not of one specific property.

In your implementation, `num.number + 10` will **not** trigger your *class* `__add__` method but rather the method of the *variable* you are operating on - in your case, an `int`.

```
num.number.__add__
```

This is why you see the output of `20` - it uses the default `__add__` 10 + 10 = 20

If you want to use the method of your *class*, you would do it like this:

```
num = Num(10)
num + 10
```

Now you are accessing your `num.__add__` method.